# How do I get the range of holidays for NETWORKDAYS from a LOOKUP?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to grab a list of holidays from another sheet using an HLOOKUP to find the appropriate row based on country to get a list of holidays for the NETWORKDAYS function. However, when I try to do this I simply get a #REF error that says HLOOKUP evaluates to an out of bounds range.

I have a sheet called Billable Days that has a list of holidays based on country. Cells J14:N14 contains the country, and in a list below that is a bunch of holiday dates. They are varying ranges. For example, the US holidays range from J15:J32.

In a different sheet, I need to pull the correct holidays based on the country in column R into a NETWORKDAYS function.

First I tried:

```
=NETWORKDAYS(B2,S1,HLOOKUP($R2,'Billable Days'!$J$14:$N$14,15:50,FALSE))
```

This gives me an #VALUE error saying: "An array value could not be found"

Then I tried:

```
=NETWORKDAYS(B2,S1,ArrayFormula(HLOOKUP($R2,'Billable Days'!$J$14:$N$14,15:50,FALSE)))
```

Which gives another value error.

Finally, I tried

```
=NETWORKDAYS(B2,S1,ArrayFormula(HLOOKUP($R2,'Billable Days'!$J$14:$N$14,{15,16,17},FALSE)))
```

Just to test it out to see if I could get any values, and got a #REF error that said "HLOOKUP evaluates to an out of bounds range"

Can anyone help me craft this function? I'm not even sure if HLOOKUP is the way to go here, but it was the only way that came to mind.

**EDIT**

For clarity and as requested, I created a sheet to demonstrate what I mean. Find it [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yuJTAsw6n-qbyan2UdVEIQtMAkgeas2iAFwRKsbRFSE/edit?usp=sharing).

You will see the Consultants and Billable Days sheets. You can see the function I wrote to calculate the NETWORKDAYS based on the start and end date. However, in that function I want to add the appropriate list of holidays from the Billable Days sheet to the NETWORKDAYS function as the third parameter. I need something that looks at the country column and finds the appropriate holiday dates from the Billable Days spreadsheet, then inserts it into the NETWORKDAYS calls. I cannot figure out how to accomplish this.

Comment: Hi whiterice, could you please share a copy of your spreadsheet to have a better idea of what you are aiming to?

Comment: I would like to but unfortunately it has a lot of business information in it. I can’t share it. How can I clear up the question?

Comment: your issue is not possible to be replicated based on your question itself. pls create a dummy spreadsheet with fake data and the same data structure and share it.

Comment: I understand. I will once I get a chance. In the meantime isn’t there a more general solution to getting a range of cells to pass to NETWORKDAYS as a list of holidays? I feel like this would be a common occurrence but couldn’t find anything searching. Maybe a function to return a reference to a bunch of cells in another sheet?

Comment: I would try to use INDIRECT() function to select the right "holidays range" based on the country but I might be wrong since I'm not 100% sure of understanding what you'd like to do. A dummy spreadsheet, as @player0 suggested, would help us in testing possible solutions.

Comment: I've made a test sheet to demonstrate. Here is the link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yuJTAsw6n-qbyan2UdVEIQtMAkgeas2iAFwRKsbRFSE/edit?usp=sharing I will edit the post too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to construct what you wish.
On the consultants sheet in L2 I placed `=address(2,match(E2, 'Billable Days'!$A$1:$F$1,0))`, which finds the column index of the desired country and construct a proper cell name for it with row B. Then in M2 I say `="'Billable Days'!"&L2&":"&mid(L2,2,1)` to construct a string referring to the desired holiday range, like `'Billable Days'!$B$2:B`. Columns L and M can be dragged down for all the people. Then when you want the holiday list for the consultant in the second row say `=INDIRECT(M2)` or in the 5th row `=INDIRECT(M5)`, or if you are building it into another formula, drop the = sign. You could clean it up a little to be graceful when the country is not found, or possibly to make an ArrayFormula and avoid the dragging.

Comment: for example see https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10tkcdKSV_jkawf_U-FX7a7n2zvGR_bwItDkqSZTneoU/edit?usp=sharing which I may not leave up forever, but is there now.

Comment: Thank you. Not exactly what I had in mind since I thought you might be able to do something directly inline without having to construct more cells, but it works.

Comment: you probably can, it would just be unreadable. Let me think on it. Sure -- INDIRECT("'Billable Days'!"&address(2,match(E2, 'Billable Days'!$A$1:$F$1,0))&":"&mid(address(2,match(E2, 'Billable Days'!$A$1:$F$1,0)),2,1))